# Get everything in a string before hyphen in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic string value which includes language and country code. I need to extract the value before hyphen and store it in a variable. How can I do this? I don't know how many characters will be there before the hyphen. I cannot use substring().
**Note**: I know how to extract after hyphen using split(). I need to get before value.

```
mystr = "eng-can";

Output:
extactedstr = "eng"
```

Comment: Why can't you use substring? You can use `slice`, which is basically the same: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: Is it okay to use split, or are you trying to avoid using it?

Comment: I am ok to use split(). Can I use it to extract before hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split it by hyphen and take the first part

```js
const mystr = "eng-can";
const firstPart = mystr.split('-')[0]
console.log(firstPart)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` to split up the string, like the following:

```js
// your string...
let myStr = "eng-can"; // your string...
let strList = myStr.split("-"); // a list
let substring = strList[0]; // first value

console.log(substring)
```

If you don't want to use `split()`, you could use a `while` loop:

```js
let myStr = "eng-can"; // your string

let value = ""; // variable to keep track of value
let i = 0; // index

while (myStr[i] !== "-" || i > myStr.length) {
  value += myStr[i]
  i++;
}


console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use split for the value before:

```
extracted = mystr.split('-')[0];
```